# How can I translate to Brazilian Portuguese the word 'approach'?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Existe alguma palavra equivalente em português para a palavra *approach*? Por exemplo dizemos quando alguém está resolvendo corretamente um exercício de matemática

> *This is the correct approach to the problem in question*

Existe alguma palavra com o mesmo sentido em português ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, existe:

> Esta é a **abordagem** correta para o problema em questão.

Vale para o verbo *to approach* também:

> I **approached** the teacher to ask him a question.
>
> **Abordei** o professor para lhe fazer uma pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

A explicacao do Ramon Melo é muito boa e pratica, no entanto se aproxima de algo literal.

Para entender completamente o significado, eu diria que na sua frase :

> This is the correct approach to the problem in question

O correct approach siginifca algo "a melhor maneira para resolver".

Para entender um pouco mais do sentido da palavra na sua totalidade, podemos imaginar uma leoa cacando na savana. Ela tem duas maneiras de chegar na presa, partindo face a face a sua presa ou chegar sorrateiramente por tras e atacar.

Veja que em ambos os casos existe a probabilidade que ela consiga atingir a presa, mas a segunda maneira seria uma forma mais segura e com mais chances de sucesso. Entao essa seria o correct approach.

Algumas vezes podemos aplicar também no sentido de "atitude certa". Por exemplo uma mae que esta dando uma bronca no filho por ter sido desobediente. Ela pode gritar e bater na crianca ou tentar conversar e explicar. Convenhamos que no sentido de educar, a segunda opcao é a correct approach.

É legal compreender a idéia da expressao, mas quando for traduzir, é mais pratico fazer como o Ramon citou.